# Gulp cwd to project root

Tags: javascript, laravel, gulp

My current code:

```
gulp.task('_sass', function() {
    var files = [
        './vendor/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss',
        './resources/assets/sass/main.scss',
        './vendor/bower_components/bootstrap-rating/bootstrap-rating.css',
        './vendor/bower_components/select2/select2.css'
    ];
    return gulp.src(files)
    //return gulp.src(files)
        .pipe(concat('all.css'))
        .pipe(sass())
        .on('error', notify.onError(function (error) {
            return "Error: " + error.message;
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css/'))
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});
```

As you can see, I have a files array where I store all the paths to the .scss files I want to concat into all.css. But I get this error:

```
Error: file to import not found or unreadable: base/normalize
Current dir: /Users/**/Code/Laravel/vendor/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/
```

which is obvious, because gulp uses the first path of the array as it's base directory. So I tried settings the `base` or the `cwd` to `'./'`, so I could specify my Laravel root directory. But that doesn't work. How can I solve this problem, so I can use all these .scss files without copying files to other directories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a tricky one, because you wouldn't need the basic working directory relative to your gulpfile, but rather relative to all your Sass components.

Am I right that  `'./resources/assets/sass/main.scss'`is your main Sass file which you use by yourself? If so, I'd suggest importing bootstrap there:

```
 @import '../../../vendor/bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap';
```

At let Sass deal with the files, Sass is usually a lot better in handling relative URLs.

Than I'd split up Sass and CSS files, bundling them later using a stream queue:

```
var queue = require('streamqueue');

gulp.task('_sass', function() {
    return queue(
        // our CSS files
        gulp.src([
            './vendor/bower_components/bootstrap-rating/bootstrap-rating.css',
            './vendor/bower_components/select2/select2.css']
        ),
        // our Sass file, compiled to CSS
        gulp.src('./resources/assets/sass/main.scss')
            .pipe(sass())
    )
    // all the rest
    .pipe(concat('all.css'))
    .on('error', notify.onError(function (error) {
        return "Error: " + error.message;
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css/'))
    .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});
```